# How can I modify Javadoc to hide specific classes

Tags: java, javadoc

I would like to get a javadoc which include documentation of all my classes out of one class. I don't want this class to be private - and then to make th javadoc over public classes only - but would like to know if there is a way I can set somewhere a name of a class that I don't want to be shown in the javadoc - or maybe there is a tag that I can put on the class and then the Javadoc does not include it.

Comment: *"modify Javadoc to hide specific classes"*  Why?  What is it supposed to do when another class references that class (e.g. as a parameter or return value of a method).

Comment: @user, you can unselect the specific class you donot want in `Generate javadoc` dialog using `eclipse export...` context menu.

Comment: I would like to hide also all references. 
I want the Javadoc to behave as it does with private classes when you choose to make it from public classes only.

Comment: @user, also hide all references? maybe you should implement your own `javadoc` program.

Comment: HiwayChe, can you please explain me how can I do that?how can I use the eclipse export to generate javadoc?

Comment: Why can't you make the class package private?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude a class from javadoc. However if the class is reference somewhere then the name will appear in that javadoc.

You are talking about hiding even that then what is the point of making javadoc if user can not see what the correct signature?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#exclude

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer I found that met my specific situation, where I had no need for the classes that I wanted to keep out of the docs, to be accessible outside of the package they were in.

So, in that situation, you DO NOT declare those classes as public and keep them in the same package as the class that uses them.

So for example, if you have a class that you need to generate JavaDocs for and that class is called CustomUtility and is declared like this:

```
public class CustomUtility {

}
```

But CustomUtility uses two other classes that are named Calculate and Process and they are not supposed to be accessible to any other classes within the scope of a project, and should not be included in your JavaDocs. You simply need to make sure that those two classes are in the same package as CustomUtility, then you declare them like this:

```
class Calculate {

}
```

and

```
class Process {

}
```

Then when you generate your JavaDocs, make sure your scope is set to Project production files, and those two classes will not be included in the JavaDocs.

Answer (score -4):

remove it from your code temporary, and genereate the coode then return it

Comment: That would most likely fail if the class is referenced by other classes that are being documented.